# The proper way to prepare a dynamic Statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, playframework-2.0

I am preparing a SQL statement from values passed through a query string. ( I am using the Play! framework. Basically what I'm running into (not really an issue just something I don't like very much) is that when I want to use `?` in the SQL string and set them later with dynamic values.

This is what I have:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM foobar_table WHERE";

if ( foo != 0 )
    sql += " AND foo=?";
if ( !bar )
    sql += " AND bar=?";

try{
    PreparedStatement getStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    if ( foo != 0 )
        getStmt.setInt(1,foo);
    if ( foo != 0 && !bar )
        getStmt.setBoolean(2, bar);
    else
        getStmt.setBoolean(1, bar);
} catch (SQLException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This does work but as you can see not very intuitive. It's OK when there are 2 dynamic values but when you get up to 5 or 6 this would just get ridiculous.

Is there an easier way of doing this to make it more flexible so that I would know how to fill in all the `?` in a better fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example (was too long for comment):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM foobar_table WHERE 1 = 1 ";
ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();

if ( foo != 0 ) {
    sql += " AND foo=?";
    paramList.add(foo);
}

if ( !bar ) {
    sql += " AND bar=?";
    paramList.add(bar);
}

try{

    PreparedStatement getStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    int index = 1;

    for (Object param : paramList) {
        getStmt.setObject(index, param);
        index++;
    }

    // execute

} catch (SQLException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Like this way the best.. nice and clean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (just rough code but you get the idea):

```
    class Param{
        final int type;
        final Object value;         
        Param(int type, Object value){
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    final List<Param> params = new ArrayList<>();

    final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM bcu_venue_events WHERE 1=1");
    int foo = 0;
    boolean bar = true;             
    if (foo != 0){
        sql.append(" AND foo=?");
        params.add(new Param(Types.INTEGER, foo));
    }       
    if (!bar){
        sql.append(" AND bar=?");
        params.add(new Param(Types.BOOLEAN, bar));
    }
    try(Connection conn = null; PreparedStatement getStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) {            
        for(int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++){
            Param p = params.get(i);
            getStmt.setObject(i + 1, p.value, p.type);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM foobar_table WHERE 1=1";

if ( foo != 0 )
    sql += " AND foo=" + foo;
if ( !bar )
    sql += " AND bar=" + bar;

try{
    PreparedStatement getStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
} catch (SQLException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: does this not leave everything open to injection? The whole point to preparing the statement is to avoid that.

Comment: you could put a check for the parameters before entering this code block. you didn't mention that the variables should be assumed to be unsafe.

Comment: Take this as a base, parameterize, but also build up an ArrayList of Objects to set later: `sql += " AND foo = ?"; paramList.add(foo);`

Comment: This is how I do it in php but because of Java is strictly typed this will not work. `foo` can be a String, boolean, int, Float, or double

Comment: `for (Object param : paramList) { preparedStatment.setObject(param); } `

Comment: no problem. any of these types can be parsed to a string in a proper way.

Comment: @Glenn can you give me an example onto what you are talking about?

Comment: @paritybit EVERYTHING should be considered unsafe when in a query string

Comment: @locrizak then give me an example on how to do injection using boolean and integer variables in this case. you can't.

Comment: `foo=1 ;DROP TABLE;` something to that effect. I thought the same thing until a buddy showed me other wise a couple months ago

Comment: it is a great imagination to get '1;DROP TABLE;' by parsing an integer :)

Comment: Well first you didn't put anything in your answer with parsing the int or bool, and second when I need to pass a String I still need to do what my question is. I'd much rather having everything go through the same process